# Postgres append multiple elements to an array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, append

I have the following table in postgres with the below schema

```
Relations 

| id | tags |
```

I need to update the field tags to append unique multiple elements to it
I can very well achieve it with like the below

```
for (String tagId : tagIds ) {

    // Execute the below query in PostGRES
    UPDATE Relations SET tags = array_append (array_remove (tags, '" + tagId + "'), '" + tagId + "') WHERE id = '" + id + "'";

}
```

But I want to append an array of elements to it in a single go without the for loop. Can someone let me know the query for that ?

Comment: Maybe: `SELECT array_cat(ARRAY['a', 'b'], ARRAY['c', 'd'])` --> {a,b,c,d}

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution.

Maybe that is an indication that you are abusing arrays and should store the tags in a table instead.